# How can I read a part of a dBase file

Tags: r, dbf, dbase

I have a very large dBase file (1.64Gb). It takes a very long time to load the whole file in R using the standard `foreign::read.dbf()` function. I would like to load only a few variables in the dataset. Does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the `read.dbf(...)` function in package `foreign` was intended for reading the `*.dbf` part of a shapefile, in which case reading in part of the file really doesn't make sense. You seem to want to do something different.

Using `RODBC` ***might*** work, depending on how your system is configured. If you're running Windows, and if you have the dBASE ODBC drivers installed, this will probably work for you (note: When you install MSOffice, it sets up a user dsn called "dBase Files", which should be accessible from `RODBC`. So if you have MSOffice installed, this should work...).

***Important Note***: This will only work if you are running a 32-bit version of R. This is because there are no 64-bit dBASE ODBC drivers. Generally, when you download 64-bit R you get both 32- and 64-bit versions, so it's just a matter of switching between them.

```
library(RODBC)
# setwd("< directory with your files >")
conn <- odbcConnect(dsn="dBASE Files")
df   <- sqlFetch(conn,"myTable",max=10)   # grab first ten rows
head(df)
#       LENGTH COASTLN010
# 1 0.02482170          1
# 2 0.01832134          2
# 3 0.03117752          3
# 4 0.04269755          4
# 5 0.02696307          5
# 6 0.05047828          6

sqlQuery(conn,"select * from myTable where LENGTH<0.008")
#       LENGTH COASTLN010
# 1 0.00625200        186
# 2 0.00634897        379
# 3 0.00733319       1583
# 4 0.00369786       1617
# 5 0.00722233       1618
# 6 0.00524176       1636
```

The example above is just meant to give you an idea of how to use `RODBC`. In this example, I have a file, `myTable.dbf` in the "directory with all your files", and this dbf has two columns, `LENGTH` and `COASTLN010` (this file actually is part of a coastline shapefile, but that is irrelevant...).

If this doesn't work try:

```
 conn <- odbcConnectDbase("myTable.dbf")
```

Comment: `odbcConnectDbase` doesn't exist. Where did you find this function ?

Comment: It's in package `RODBC`, along with `odbcConnect(...)`.