# How to read a large dbf file in chunks with R

Tags: r, bigdata, dbf, data-import

I have a 23G DBF file. Let's say it has 3 columns: x y z and 1000 rows (for illustration purpose). I only need the rows that have y from the followings c("good,"excellent","perfect"). And save the rows as a .csv file.

Actually, I don't know what y is really called in the big file, maybe 'yy' or 'Idontknow'. So the first thing is to check the headers so I know what column I should use for filtering.

I know there may first construct a connection and then read in data in chunks using functions such as read.table() and read.fwf(). However, this idea does not seem to work for DBF files.

Any tips?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177062/how-can-i-read-a-part-of-a-dbase-file/26189680#26189680

Comment: This is something I don't want to do with R, but from the command line (I'd use the terminal on Mac OS). You can stream the data instead of trying to get all in memory. You could use the `awk` program for instance, or write a Python program to do this. Alternatively you can try to read the data in a database like `sqlite` or `postgres` and query your data from there.

Comment: @DieterMenne: The package mentioned in the post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177062/how-can-i-read-a-part-of-a-dbase-file/26189680#26189680) is not available for OS Yosemite users.